# How to get values from a ArrayList in one class and use them in another class

Tags: java, android, arraylist, custom-adapter

I'm trying to retrieve values from a Arraylist which is in another class, in the first class I have:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getListaCategorias() {
    return listaCategorias;
}
```

And now in my other class I'm trying to get the values which are inside that ArrayList and insert them into a TextView:

```
TodasAsCategorias todasAsCategorias = new TodasAsCategorias();
todasAsCategorias.getListaCategorias();

TextView txtDesignacao = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Designacao);
txtDesignacao.setText("Values from the ArrayList");
```

The problem is getting the values out of the ArrayList and insert them into the TextView, the idea is to have a ListView where every single one of those values goes to one item (txtDesignacao is the TextView which is inside the list_item), I can't really use a SimpleAdapter because my ListView as some special attributes that's why I'm using a CustomAdapter

#### EDIT

I declared the arraylist as static but now I have a error with the:

> TodasAsCategorias todasAsCategorias = array.get(i);

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array = TodasAsCategorias.getListaCategorias();
TodasAsCategorias todasAsCategorias = array.get(i);
TextView txtDesignacao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Designacao);
txtDesignacao.setText("Values from the ArrayList");
```

It says incompatible types, requires the class TodasAsCategorias, found HashMap

Comment: one option is static variable or method

Comment: you want to set a text component from an ArrayList ?

Comment: @davidxxx yes, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array = getListaCategorias();
TodasAsCategorias todasAsCategorias = array.get(i);
TextView txtDesignacao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Designacao);
txtDesignacao.setText("Values from the ArrayList");
```

Comment: But I want to set the value from the arraylist to the TextView